# Router connected to internet but devices have limited connectivity

Tags: internet, lan, connection

My router is showing that it has a solid connection to the internet however when I connect any device, they have limited connection.

It happened when I rebooted my router due to a sudden slow connection. I have reset my router and also factory reset it but the same thing is happening.

The issue is occurring on both wireless and via wired connection.

[image: /ipconfig and DHCP settings in router]
[image: Status on router]

Comment: is DHCP working on the router?

Comment: Yes it appears to be working

Comment: do connected devices show a valid address in your DHCP range, or do they show a self-assigned address 169.254.x.x ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like either some other device is also delivering DHCP or your routers DHCP is wrongly configured.

So firstly, make sure nothing else on your network can deliver DHCP (Wi-Fi access points and servers mainly).

Can you share the output of `ipconfig` for the relevant interface?

You should have an address in the same network as your router so if your router has an address of 192.168.1.1, your devices should have addresses somewhere between 192.168.1.2 and 192.168.1.254. They should have a netmask normally of 255.255.255.0 and a default gateway pointing to the router.

Usually, the DHCP server on the router will be configured to deliver a subset of addresses such as 192.168.1.100 - 192.168.1.150

**UPDATE**: Next step is to look at the router firewall to make sure nothing is being blocked. Then also check with your ISP to make sure they don't have any issues. Do both wired and wireless devices all have the same problem? Is there a mobile device that works.

Check also for DNS issues. Currently, you are using your ISP's DNS servers. Try Google's or OpenDNS.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of my DHCP settings and /ipconfig but for some reason the DHCP is working now with no internet.

Comment: Can you read anything from that screenshots.?

Comment: Yes, just zoom in